# Spring Cloud Zuul Doesn't Relay Access Token

Tags: spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-netflix

I am trying to use Spring Cloud Zuul as an api/authentication gateway.  I have successfully implemented bearer token authorization for my service behind zuul and I successfully have Zuul forwarding to my form login and routing back to my application, but I cannot get Zuul to pass the bearer token to the service.

My Zuul configuration is as follows:

```
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application { ... }
```

My service configuration is as follows:

```
@Profile("oauth")
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableWebSecurity
public static class InternalApiGatewayConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
```

When my Angular app tries to access my service through zuul, I get

```
{"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"Full authentication is required to access this resource"}
```

I have managed to work around this issue by putting the following code in a ZuulFilter, but it doesn't seem right:

```
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    OAuth2AuthenticationDetails details = (OAuth2AuthenticationDetails)authentication.getDetails();
    String tokenValue = details.getTokenValue();
    ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + tokenValue);
```

My understanding is that Zuul should automatically send the bearer token value.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

So I've figured out the answer to my own question, and it was painfully simple.  My project imported `spring-security-oauth2`.  I simply needed to add a dependency on `spring-cloud-security` as well.  With that, I did not have to implement a ZuulFilter at all.

Comment: Yes .. Thank you .I was also added just only `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul` and zuul's requests didnot send with `authorization: bearer <access_token>`. Adding `spring-cloud-security` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Btw this is the solution that works without spring-cloud-security

```
@Component
public class TokenRelayFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Set<String> headers = (Set<String>) ctx.get("ignoredHeaders");
        // JWT tokens should be relayed to the resource servers
        headers.remove("authorization");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 10000;
    }
}
```